# Can't log new state right after setting the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to get the newest `state` right after setting it. Note: The change is triggered by typing in the `input`.

```
import { useReducer } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const initialState = { value: "Initial state", elements: [] };

  const [state, setState] = useReducer(
    (state: any, updates: any) => ({ ...state, ...updates }),
    initialState
  );

  function handleInputChange(event: any) {
    // setState({
    //   value: event.target.value,
    //   elements: [{ text: event.target.value }]
    // });

    const newState = {
      value: event.target.value,
      elements: [{ text: event.target.value }]
    };

    setState((prevState: any) => {
      return { ...prevState, ...newState };
    });

    console.log(state.value);
    console.log(state.elements);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        id="input"
        type="text"
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        value={state.value}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

With this:

```
setState({
  value: event.target.value,
  elements: [{ text: event.target.value }]
});
```

The `console.log`'s would log the old values. For example, if you typed `a`, they would log: `Initial state` and `[]` respectively. Instead of what I expected: `a` and `[Object]`.

So I tried to set `state` with a function instead, hoping that I'd get the latest value of `state`:

```
setState((prevState: any) => {
  return { ...prevState, ...newState };
});
```

However, I'm getting `Initial state` and `[]` again ... this time not matter how many times I type in the `input`.

How can I get the latest value of `state`?

**Live code:**

[image: Edit useState same value rerender (forked)]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first approach

```
setState({
  value: event.target.value,
  elements: [{ text: event.target.value }]
});
console.log(state.value);
console.log(state.elements);
```

results in out-of-date values being logged because the call to a state setter [doesn't result in the state being updated immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253). You must wait for the component to re-render before the new values are returned by `useReducer` and subsequently put into the `state` variable.

The second approach

```
setState((prevState: any) => {
  return { ...prevState, ...newState };
});
```

doesn't work because you're now passing a function to the reducer, so in the reducer:

```
(state: any, updates: any) => ({ ...state, ...updates }),
```

the above resolves to

```
(state: any, updates: any) => ({ ...state, ...theFunctionYouPassed }),
```

But functions don't have enumerable own properties, so the returned object is no different from the initial `state`.

`useReducer` is not the same as `useState`, and your use of the `setState` variable name (rather than the more conventional `dispatch`) may be throwing you off. If you want to use the functional form of state updates (though it wouldn't help anything in this particular situation), use `useState` instead.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ value: "Initial state", elements: [] });

  function handleInputChange(event) {
    const newState = {
      value: event.target.value,
      elements: [{ text: event.target.value }]
    };
    setState((prevState) => {
      return { ...prevState, ...newState };
    });
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state.value);
    console.log(state.elements);
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        id="input"
        type="text"
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        value={state.value}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Or change your reducer to accept a function.

```js
const { useReducer, useEffect } = React;

// An example of how you would type and use useReducer
// to accept a callback, like useState's does:

/*
type State = { value: string, elements: Array<{ text: string }>};
const reducer = (
  state: State,
  stateUpdater: (oldState: State) => State
) => stateUpdater(state)
*/
const reducer = (state, stateUpdater) => stateUpdater(state);
const App = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { value: "Initial state", elements: [] });

  function handleInputChange(event) {
    const newState = {
      value: event.target.value,
      elements: [{ text: event.target.value }]
    };
    dispatch((prevState) => {
      return { ...prevState, ...newState };
    });
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state.value);
    console.log(state.elements);
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        id="input"
        type="text"
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        value={state.value}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

You also might consider avoiding `any`, which defeats the purpose of TypeScript - typing things properly helps turn runtime errors into easier-to-solve compile-time errors.

Comment: Thank a lot for the detailed explanation and the code! So you can't log something after setting a state. You can only log inside an `useEffect` watching that state?